# What is the downside of XInitThreads()?

Tags: multithreading, qt, x11

I know `XInitThreads()` will allow me to do calls to the X server from threads other than the main thread, and that concurrent thread support in Xlib is necessary if I want to make [OpenGL calls from secondary threads using Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq06-glimpsing.html#writingmultithreadedglapplications). I have such a need for my application, but in a very rare context. Unfortunately, XInitThreads() needs to be called at the very beginning of my application's execution and will therefore affect it whether I need it or not for a particular run (I have no way of knowing before I run the app if I do need multithreaded OpenGL support or not).

I'm pretty sure the overall behavior the the application will remain unchanged if I uselessly call XInitThread(), but programming is all about tradeoffs, and I'm pretty sure there's a reason multithread support is not the default behavior for Xlib.

[The man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/XInitThreads.3.html) says that it is recommended that single-threaded programs not call this function, but it doesn't say why. What's the tradeoff when calling XInitThreads()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It creates a global lock and also one on each Display, so each call into Xlib will do a lock/unlock. If you instead do your own locking (keep your Xlib usage in a single thread at a time with your own locks) then you could in theory have less locking overhead by taking your lock, doing a lot of Xlib stuff at once, and then dropping your lock. Or in practice most toolkits use a model where they don't lock at all but just require apps to use X only in the main UI thread.

Since many Xlib calls are blocking (they wait for a reply from the server) lock contention could be an issue.

There are also some semantic pains with locking per-Xlib-call on Display; between each Xlib call on thread A, in theory any other Xlib call could have been made on thread B. So threads can stomp on each other in terms of confusing the display state, even though only one of them makes an Xlib request at a time. That is, XInitThreads() is preventing crashes/corruption due to concurrent Display access, but it isn't really taking care of any of the semantic considerations of having multiple threads sharing an X server connection.

I think the need to make your own semantic sense out of concurrent display access is one reason that people don't bother with XInitThreads per-Xlib-call locking. Since they end up with application-level or toolkit-level locks anyway.

One approach here is to open a separate Display connection in each thread, which could make sense depending on what you are doing.

Another approach is to use the newer xcb API rather than Xlib; xcb is designed from scratch to be multithreaded and nonblocking.

Historically there have also been some bugs in XInitThreads() in some OS/Xlib versions, though I don't remember any specifics, I do remember seeing those go by.